# Several Dynamic Actions on one IR region

Tags: jquery, oracle, oracle-apex

Here is an example from a simple project without a lot of bells and whistles. One DA jQuery Selector `#my_static_project td:nth-child(9)` and second DA jQuery Selector `#my_static_project td:not(:last-child):not(:nth-child(9)):not(:nth-child(10))`
Both actions work flawlessly until you click a cell in the ninth column. Then you clicked a cell in another column and both DA worked. Also, both DA continue to work with the rest of the rows of one IR region. I tried to disable one of them, the second continues to work, although it shouldn't. What could be the reason for this behavior?

A piece of code, maybe it's in it:

```js
{"triggeringElementType":"JQUERY_SELECTOR","triggeringElement":"#my_static_project td:nth-child(9)","bindType":"bind","bindEventType":"click","anyActionsFireOnInit":false,actionList:[{"eventResult":true,"executeOnPageInit":false,"stopExecutionOnError":true,"affectedElementsType":"REGION","affectedRegionId":"my_static_project",javascriptFunction:function (){ $('#my_static_project tr').on('click', function() {
  var bckg = $(this).children("td:nth-child(9)").css("background-color");
        if (bckg == "rgb(252, 240, 103)"){
        $(this).children("td:nth-child(9)").css("background-color","rgb(249, 249, 249)");
        //$(this).children("td:nth-child(9)").removeAttribute("style");
        }
        else
        {
        $(this).children("td:nth-child(9)").css("background-color","rgb(252, 240, 103)");
        }
});
}
```

After removing ridiculous errors, it worked

```js
  var bckg = $(this).css("background-color");
        if (bckg == "rgb(252, 240, 103)"){
        $(this).css("background-color","rgb(249, 249, 249)");
        //$(this).children("td:nth-child(9)").removeAttribute("style");
        }
        else
        {
        $(this).css("background-color","rgb(252, 240, 103)");
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML and jQuery?

Comment: It's not difficult for me to show. I repeat that the example is quite simple. I use
Product Build 20.2.0.00.20 on apex.oracle.com The answer is enough for me that such selectors in this situation are normal, otherwise I can play around myself.

Comment: You don't want to show your HTML?

Comment: @FSDford, it is about **Oracle Application Express* and its Interactive Report. There's no much HTML to share.